# How to map a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, hash, collect

Is there a better way to map a Ruby hash? I want to iterate over each pair and collect the values. Perhaps using tap?

```
hash = { a:1, b:2 }

output = hash.to_a.map do |one_pair|
  k = one_pair.first
  v = one_pair.last  
  "#{ k }=#{ v*2 }"
end

>> [
  [0] "a=2",
  [1] "b=4"
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby's [hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) includes the [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) module which includes the [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) function.

```
hash = {a:1, b:2}
hash.map { |k, v| "#{k}=#{v * 2}" }
```

[Enumerable#map | RubyDocs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

Answer (score 3):

Err, yes, with `map`, invoked directly on the hash:

```
{ a:1, b:2 }.map { |k,v| "#{k}=#{v*2}" } # => [ 'a=2', 'b=4' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = { a:1, b:2 }
hash.map{|k,v| [k,v*2]* '='}
# => ["a=2", "b=4"]
```